# Query system specs (cpu, memory, data disks, free space) using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, scripting

Is there an ability to query below system specifications using T-SQL?

1. cpu (show number of processors / cores / frequency)
2. memory (show total amount of RAM on a machine; show allocated RAM; show really used RAM)
3. data disks (show total number of disks, their volume, free space available)
4. show Windows edition and version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you bet. Let's start with the [open source First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/master) (disclaimer: I'm one of the script authors) - install sp_Blitz, and then:

sp_Blitz @CheckServerInfo = 1

And at the bottom, you get a bunch of information about your system:

[image: sp_Blitz output]

I've taken the liberty of rearranging the columns a little in that screenshot because I want to show you the finding, details, and the CheckID.

When you see a CheckID that has information you want to use, open up the sp_Blitz script and do a search for that CheckID. For example, if you want to know how we're determining that you have 4 logical processors and 31GB RAM, do a control-F for 84 (the CheckID), and you'll see the dynamic management views (DMVs) where we're gathering that data from.

Check 84 is a great example because it requires different logic based on what version of SQL Server you're trying to check, too.

Rather than giving you the specific answers for each of the 4 questions you asked, I'm just teaching you this process because I bet if you need those 4 things, you probably need a lot more, too - and you'll find a lot of 'em in sp_Blitz. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here what can help to view system specs:

Stored procedure **"ViewServerProperties"** - shows information about server (hardware) and instance of SQL Server along with some other configuration information

https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools - "ViewServerProperties"

Install it in any database and run "exec ViewServerProperties"

Comment: FYI: For versions like 2014 and maybe others,  socket_count, cores_per_socket, and sql_memory_model_desc  do not exist in the system view sys.dm_os_sys_info. So I don't think it will work on older but still supported versions like 2014.

Comment: Thanks @BCM, I will check that out!

Answer (score 0):

I use xp_cmdshell to do this.  You can invoke the command line and even PowerShell from SQL with a simple `Exec xp_cmdshell 'command here'`  All you have to do is turn it on via advanced options.